# Оплатить / уплатить

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: подлежит "уплате" или "оплате"? Обязан "уплатить" или "оплатить"?

Answer (score 3):

Уплачивают *деньги* (в различных формах, суммах), оплачивают *деньгами* стоимость, труд, проезд. Цену "платят" (*заплатить цену*). **Стоимость** подлежит **оплате** - путём *уплаты денег* кому-либо за что-либо.

Answer (score 0):

Оплатить — когда речь идёт о том, за что платят: товар, проезд, коммунальные услуги и тому подобное. Его часто можно сравнить с глаголом «получать». Он оплатил (заплатил за что? и получил что?) интернет.

Уплатить — когда речь идёт о том, что платят (об эквиваленте денег): пошлина, штраф, комиссионные, квартплата, выкуп и так далее. Это слово, наоборот, по значению ближе к «отдавать». Он уплатил (заплатил что?) налоги.